# get location of "c" in for loop?

Tags: python

For context, I'm making a basic hangman game.

In my code I have two lists. Letters[] and Display[]. Letters[] is a randomly generated word broken up by characters, like this:

```
['e', 'x', 'a', 'm', 'p', 'l', 'e']
```

Display[] is a list of dashes, one per every letter in letters[]:

```
['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
```

I am attempting to use a for loop to check if a user's input (var: input) is equal to any letter in Letters[].

```
def start():
    global input
    input = raw_input(">")
    print input
    guess()


def guess():
    for c in letters:
        if c == input:
        #?

start()
```

What I want to be able to do: append the returned letter in the if statement in the same location it was returned from to the display[] list and have it replace the '-' that would be there. The problem is, I do not know if it is possible, or how to find the location of returned value c.

Comment: Get rid of the `global`. Unless you can explain in detail what it does you won't need it and when you know what it does you don't want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to add a counter to your loop:

```
for i, c in enumerate(letters):
    if c == input:
        # i is the position.
```

The alternative would be to keep a manual count:

```
i = 0
for c in letters:
    if c == input:
        # i is the position
    i += 1
```

or use `xrange(len(letters))` to generate sequence of indices:

```
for i in range(len(letters)):
    if letters[i] == input:
        # i is the position
```

but `enumerate()` is more concise and faster.

Comment: Thanks much. I used enumerate() and insert() and got this working great!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate` to get the index.

But as your code currently stands, it has multiple issues.

First, it's better to pass some parameters to the function `guess()` rather than using global variable. And you can do a while loop to enable people to guess multiple times.

```
def start():
    letters = "example" # You don't need it to be a list, a string is already a list in Python
    display = ['-']*len(letters)
    while True:
        guess_char = raw_input(">")
        guess(guess_char)
        print ''.join(display)
        if ''.join(display)==letters:
            print 'Finally you have guessed it!'
            break

def guess(guess_char):
    for idx, true_char in enumerate(letters):
        if true_char==guess_char:
            display[idx] = true_char
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write out the entire thing for me, but I was hoping to create this on my own as a learning experience, with as little help as possible, hence the more specific question. So yes, there will be errors galore in my code, but its more about creating a project that is my own, that just works.

Answer (score 0):

Zip the letters with the dashes and compare it to the user input (here called `letter`):

```
def undash (dashes, letters, letter):
    return [l if l == letter else d for d, l in zip (dashes, letters) ]
```

Example usage:

```
>>> d = ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
>>> letters = ['e', 'x', 'a', 'm', 'p', 'l', 'e']
>>> d = undash (d, letters, 'q')
>>> d
['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
>>> d = undash (d, letters, 'e')
>>> d
['e', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 'e']
>>> d = undash (d, letters, 'x')
>>> d
['e', 'x', '-', '-', '-', '-', 'e']
>>> d = undash (d, letters, 'm')
>>> d
['e', 'x', '-', 'm', '-', '-', 'e']
```

And here a sample game:

```
def undash (dashes, word, letter):
    return ''.join(c if c == letter else d for d, c in zip (dashes, word) )

word = 'supercalifragilisticexpialidocious'
dashes = ''.join ('-' for _ in word)

while '-' in dashes:
    print dashes
    c = raw_input ('Your guess: ')
    dashes = undash (dashes, word, c)
print word
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am attempting to use a for loop to check if a user's input (var: input) is equal to any letter in Letters[].

If that is all you are trying to do you can use the `in` keyword.

Since strings are basically lists of individual characters, all of the list operations still apply.

```
if 'a' in 'abcde':
    print "The letter is in the string!"
```

See: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange